# How to interprete interaction terms when one of terms is squared?

Tags: regression

I'm designing a regression to test the relationship between A and B, and how their relationship might effect X. The model I have considered is:

X= A + B + AxB + Ax(B^2)

Since my hypothesis is that at different levels of B, the relationship between A and B might have a different effect on X. I have run the regression and I found that both interaction terms are statistically significant, however the coefficient for AxB is positive and Ax(B^2) negative. Any suggestion what this could possibly mean?

Comment: Can you give more information? What are `X`, `A`, and `B`?